# Using matlab to animate points on a wave equation

Tags: matlab, math, pde

The question is as follows.

[image]

I took the graduate level PDE and well understand what above equations mean. It is a wave equation with boundary & initial conditions. However, I never used matlab to do such "movie" thing before and has no idea how to achieve it. Can anyone provide some help? Thank you.

Comment: Create a [uniformly spaced `t` vector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html). For each value of `t`, generate a plot, [write the plot as a frame in a "movie"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter-object.html). Alternatively, [save each plot as an image file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html) and generate the "movie" externally.

Comment: down voting homework question

Comment: @crowdedComputeeer Ok you have the right to down vote. My major is MATH not programming, and this course is not about MATLAB at all. And I have spent two hours reading materials about solving that PDE. I am not asking for solution, I am just asking for some help with making "movie", some hint that can save me from meaningless google. I believe this is what stack exchange is for.

Comment: @Sherry fair enough. sorry if I prejudged. if you post some code describing/implementing the PDE and boundary conditions and a plot of one time instance, I'll post code on how to make it a movie from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine the `movie` function is what you're after.

You create a plot for each frame of the movie and add it to the movie using `getframe`. You can then show the movie using `movie` or turn it into a .avi using `movie2avi`.

Here's a simplistic example:

```
step = 0.1;
x = 0:step:2*pi;
for i = 1:2*pi/step
    phi=i*step;
    y = sin(x + phi);
    plot(x,y);
    M(i) = getframe();
end

close all;

movie(M)
```

Matlab also give an [example](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movie.html)

Beware, building up the movie can be quite a slow process in my experience